# How to read Windows's Environment variables from php using built-in webserver?

Tags: php, windows

I use Azure to deploy my code, so I'm using server's variables to save important settings (like client_id and client_secrets).

`$_SERVER['APPSETTING_Imgur_Client_Id'];`

[Set Azure Application Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOREP.png)

[Azure $_SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irUuu.png)

I would like to use the same mecanism in my development environnement (Windows), by setting Environnement variables (directly to windows) and use them in my app.

So I have defined 2 Windows Variables (`system properties->Environment Variables->User Variables`):

[Set Windows's Evironment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu9gg.png)

But thoses variables aren't available through `$_SERVER['APPSETTING_Imgur_Client_Id'];` (with `php -S [::]:80 index.php` cmd).
I got only default $_SERVER variables.

So I'm askying:

- How to read thoses Windows's evironment variables with php?
- If we can't how to add custom $_SERVER variables (without using the php application code).

---

I'm using:

```
PHP 7.1.10
&
Windows Server 2016
```

I have changed the locations of variables (now under `System variables`) and restarted my computer.

But after that, even with `getenv('APPSETTING_Imgur_Client_Id'')` or `$_SERVER` I can't access to my custom variables.

But with command line `php -r 'var_export($_SERVER);'` I can see my variables

If I want to edit my code, I clone the repo and launch the webserver from the local directory with `php -S [::]:80 index.php`.
It seam that the `php -S` command doesn't pass windows environment.

Thanks you.

Edit: Solution:

use `getenv` see picture below:

[Postman sample, with both user env and system env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U06yK.png)

Comment: @NineBerry Your answer was correct, `getenv('somevar')` works, not `$_SERVER['somevar']`. Should I roll back to previous question ? Or should I post an answer ? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getenv` function.

Documentation at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php](http://php.net/manual/de/function.getenv.php)

Note that the variables set under `system properties->Environment Variables->User Variables` can not be seem by a web server when the web server runs under a different user account. You need to set the variables via `system properties->Environment Variables-> System Variables` (and then restart the web server to have them available)

Comment: I have changed the locations of variables (now under `System variables`) and restarted my computer.

But after that, even with `getenv('APPSETTING_Imgur_Client_Id'')` or `$_SERVER` I can't access to my custom variables.

Edit:
But with command line `php -r 'var_export($_SERVER);'` I can see my variables

Comment: @user8738918 what exactly is your setup for testing your php code?

Comment: If I want to edit my code, I clone the repo and launch the webserver from the local directory with `php -S [::]:80 index.php`.
So I have a php7 and a windows server 2016 (10.0.14393).

It seam that the `php -S` command doesn't pass windows environment.

Comment: @user8738918
same problem. seems php loads "user env variables" instead of "system env variables", so when you run php from browser - it loads from user "default" with his own env, in case of you write "php -r" while you run CLI from your current user with your env. -- Still dont know how to load "system variables"